# Tons of errors after configuing autolayout

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, autolayout

I just learned to use autolayout and I have my app functioning properly, problem is I got like 30 werrors. So far all I have done is sert horizontal aligmnets to buttons and labels, and pinned objects. These are the errors

MainStoryboardiPad.storyboard Frame for "Button - Configure" will be different at run time.

MainStoryboardiPad.storyboard: Vertical position is ambiguous for "Button - Configure".

And I got about thirty of these for labels and buttons. Is there another step to autolayout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select (highlight) all the views with problems, then choose from the top menu, Editor->Resolve Autolayout Issues->Reset to suggested constraints. That should clear all those errors.

Comment: Thanks, a simmple and easy solution

Answer (score 1):

Frame will be different at run time: this means that the location of a frame on the storyboard is different than where your constraints dictate it should be.

Ambiguous: this means that you're missing some constraints.

To resolve these issues, if you open up your storyboard, you'll see yellow or red arrows beside certain scenes on the list to the left. Clicking the arrow will reveal a view with all the issues with that scene. To fix the "frame will be different at run time" error, change the x, y, width, and height of the frame rectangle of the view with the wrong frame. To fix the ambiguous warning, add extra constraints.